# How to discover APIs in Google OAuth2 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth

I've got a problem with .discover method in Node.js. I've got such a piece of code:

```
googleapis.discover('oauth2', 'v2').execute(function(err, client){
    if(!err)
        callback(client);
});
```

And it throws error: TypeError: Object # has no method 'discover'
But in all tutorials there is such a method mentioned. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Please post the link from the tutorial. I would like to see what you are using as an example.

Comment: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/node-and-google-oauth/

Comment: I have never used oAuth alone. I have always used it together with the application I want to use oAuth with. So, what are you trying to use oAuth with?

Comment: I thought it can be without any application because I only need email, first name and last name to retrieve from Google. So I don't know. It can be calendar for example.

Comment: Does anyone know what's wrong? :(

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Use oAuth for verification for your app, right? Have you tried using Discover as the tutorial does? See if it works when you discover calendar and oAuth together.

Comment: Yes you're right. I tried it and it also throws the same error ;/

Comment: Are you sure your `googleapis` object is the same as the example's? Note that that example comes from another file in some "example" folder.

Comment: What is being used to populate "Client"?

Comment: Also, make sure you are referencing any needed scripts. Often these vague errors occur when something is missing.

Comment: Google libraries for Node are relatively new. That's why I decided to make it other way because I think that sdks have changed since writting this tutorial and something can work in a different way. Now I'm using example given in Google's Github (I think it's the most actual) and when I'll come to terms with that I'll write what was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error. I think they updated the googleapis client for Node.

Try follow the new syntax or use older version:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: oauth2Client });
```

Comment: I also think so. I used passport-google-oauth library for Node. It's very simple library that lets us easily authenticate the user using Google OAuth2 or the previous version. Here's link to GitHub: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. But after looking around for a few hours. I came across this question and realized they might have changed the API and haven't updated the official documentation.

I was also trying this piece of code from this link (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-nodejs)

```js
var googleapis = require('googleapis'),
    readline = require('readline');

var CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR CLIENT ID HERE',
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET HERE',
    REDIRECT_URL = 'YOUR REDIRECT URL HERE',
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var auth = new googleapis.OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);

googleapis.discover('drive', 'v2').execute(function(err, client) {
  var url = auth.generateAuthUrl({ scope: SCOPE });
  var getAccessToken = function(code) {
    auth.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      auth.credentials = tokens;
      upload();
    });
  };
  var upload = function() {
    client.drive.files
      .insert({ title: 'My Document', mimeType: 'text/plain' })
      .withMedia('text/plain', 'Hello World!')
      .withAuthClient(auth).execute(console.log);
  };
  console.log('Visit the url: ', url);
  rl.question('Enter the code here:', getAccessToken);
});
```

After trying for hours and hours. I changed my quickstart.js to this after looking at some other docs/tutorials on the internet.

```js
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = googleapis.auth.OAuth2;
var readline = require('readline');

var CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR CLIENT ID HERE',
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET HERE',
    REDIRECT_URL = 'YOUR REDIRECT URL HERE',
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
var drive = googleapis.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: oauth2Client });

var execute = function(err, client) {  
  var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({ scope: SCOPE });
  var getAccessToken = function(code) {
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
      upload();
    });
  };
  var upload = function() {
    console.log(client)
    client.drive.files
      .insert({ title: 'My Document', mimeType: 'text/plain' })
      .withMedia('text/plain', 'Hello World!')
      .withAuthClient(oauth2Client).execute(console.log);
  };
  console.log('Visit the url: ', url);
  rl.question('Enter the code here:', getAccessToken);
};

execute();
```

It started working but although I got it to output the URL to go to, I get an error after pasting the authorization code from the URL. The Client object in the upload function is undefined so I get an type error saying "cannot read property 'drive' of undefined". If someone knows the problem, please do let me know. I am also just learning NodeJS.